# Starting to Deal with Duplicate Tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

How are other beta sites dealing with duplicate tags?

For example, [applications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) (most popular) vs. [apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apps) vs. [android-app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app). These bring up three different sets of questions that are all about apps.

(BTW android-app is redundant and should be removed regardless since the site only covers android apps to begin with...)

Comment: See also: **Can we black-list the Android-tag?** http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/17/can-we-black-list-the-android-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just converted all `apps` and `android-app` tags to the `applications` tag.

I also created synonyms, [please vote](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/applications/synonyms) :)

Comment: You may be the only one with enough rep to vote yet.  Braggart.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I totally thought the same thing about the 'android-app' tag being redundant.

We should choose which one is the "authoritative" tag and edit all the questions to use that one.  I vote we use "applications".

(Is there a way to blacklist tags?)

Comment: I went ahead and did this.  Applications is set up to have the other two as synonyms.  I sent a tweet to Jeff about blacklisting tags.